# Is it acceptable to initialize temporary strings to keep conditionals readable?

Tags: c++, string, char, hex, conditional-statements

This applies to any language, but for now, let's look at c++. Suppose we have two chars that must take a hexadecimal value:

```
char b, t;

do {
    //some code

} while(((b<'0' || b>'9') && (b<'A' || b>'F')) || ((t<'0' || t>'9') && (t<'A' || t>'F')));
```

*Phew* that last conditional looks scary. Let's look at an alternate:

```
char b, t;

do {
    //some code

} while(string(1,b).find_first_of("0123456789ABCDEF")==-1 || string(1,t).find_first_of("0123456789ABCDEF")==-1);
```

The code still looks very messy, but at least we can understand what is going on: a couple of strings are initialized to see if there is a hex character in them.

Assuming there is no difference in performance, is the second solution better than the first one, or is there another way to see if a char contains a hex value without inflating the code?

The chars' case can be changed in the loop to ALLCAPS or lowercase, if necessary (currently ALLCAPS).

Comment: Even if `std::isxdigit` didn't exist, the correct thing to do in cases like this would be to write a function that does that check.  `while(somefunc(b) || somefunc(t))` is much better than either of those two options.

Comment: I would say that code clarity should almost always take priority over performance. In most programs, most of the time goes into executing a small portion of the code, and programmers tend to be very bad at guessing which portions those are (something that will only get worse as compilers get better at optimizing code). In my own work, I only start to worry about the code performance when I've run it, seen that it's too slow, and then run a profiler to identify what portion of the code is taking so long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [std::isxdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit).

Comment: Amazing. I never knew there was such a nice function.